# Cancel button on a java splash screen

Tags: java, swing, button, awt, splash-screen

Is it possible to have a cancel button on `SplashScreen` so the user can cancel application start?
How?

Comment: By `SplashScreen` do you explicitly mean [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html)?

Answer (score 1):

A splash screen is just a Borderless window(which you can create using JFrame). You can add a panel that will have a JButton which inturn calls System.exit(0); instead of loading the application.

```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel Loading");
    cancel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){/*add listener, call System.exit(0);*/}); 
    panel.add(cancel);
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    //set image of the label which will be your application's icon
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 200); //400x200 splash screen
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: A JWindow is a better approach.

Comment: @M.M.  Pure AWT is the best option.  As used by most open source splash screens, and Sun/Oracle's own [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson JFrame internally uses AWT's Frame I think. I agree with you folks. :-)

Comment: *"JFrame internally uses AWT's Frame I think."*  No, it extends it, different thing.  And that is missing the point that you don't want to be loading ***any*** Swing classes in a splash.  The existing splashes use AWT only, for the sake of speed of loading the required JRE classes.

Comment: I would just `addActionListener()` to `cancel` button, so that the action is executed regardless of HID device used by the user (mouse/keyboard)

Comment: @AndrewThompson curious - any measurements on that assumed performance? Always thought the splash being a convenience thingy and can't recall complaints about full-fledged swing splashes, but then without direct comparison probably nobody would notice a less-than split-second diff :-)

Comment: ahh ... read the doc of splash: _The splash screen can be displayed at application startup, before the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) starts_ - looks like it is not even java. And null on this machine (vista), so unavailable for curiosity :-)

Comment: if the splash screen is displayed before the JVM starts, then there is no way to add 'cancel' button on it and have it executed. Most don't know when a JVM was loaded(happens behind the screen). Now I am showing a Splashscreen after JVM has loaded and I dont think anyone would notice.

Comment: @kleopatra  That's a good point that I missed.  I wonder how they manage to use an AWT class before the JVM starts..  No I have not made my own measurements, but based that comment on reports that the JRE could load classes package by package, together with the tendency to use only AWT.

Comment: So a splash screen is a Native Widget - loaded by your application's loader(making a JNI call perhaps?).

Comment: seems native: looking at the code reveals that they are loading a library, getting a pointer into that and doing all manipulation in native methods using that ptr ... all far away from anything I want to know :-)